# Question about Servers, Ports and banner grabbing

Tags: linux, server, port

These quarantine i took some networking lessons because i had the time to understand them properly. However, i have some questions and curiosities. First one: Is it possible to banner grab a service other than http or ftp, for example VNC. I remember i seen somewhere on a blog, a pentester was searching for VNC servers without authentication and he passed the parameter "authentication=false" to the shodan engine. Now where does shodan got that in the first place? From the banner, or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

A banner is simply metadata about a service. It can contain whatever information you decide it should contain. Shodan decided that for VNC it includes information about whether the service has authentication disabled. For HTTP it means headers, for FTP it means welcome string and results from running a few commands, etc. You can generate a banner for any service but the content will be different based on who generated the banner and the type of service.